# Codeigniter return not found on the server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I just uploaded my application into another server (worked well on the previous), but now I get this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /lk/installation was not found on this server.
```

I suspect that there are some issues with the `.htaccess` which have the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the controller `installation` is declared as: `Installation.php`, but I repeat, the application worked well on the previous server so there aren't technical problem like class name declaration or something like. Must be a problem of configuration of the server, noticed that I get not found with the server page not CodeIgniter page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a name declaration problem if the previous server was Windows and the new one is Linux. Windows **is not** case sensitive, but Linux **is** case sensitive.

So `Installation.php` must define the class using uppercase first e.g

```
class Installation extends CI_Controller {
```

The other thing to test is that .htaccess is working - assuming you use it. If you are and this URL fails

```
https://example.com/installation
```

But this URL works

```
https://example.com/index.php/installation
```

Then .htaccess isn't working as expected.

Comment: nope I was having a problem in the server configuration, I missed AllowOverride All to apache. I accepted your answer for the efforts, thanks